# Why does sort -u treat U+2161 and U+2162 as the same character?

Tags: linux, sorting, unicode, gnu-coreutils

I have a file with two characters each on its own line:

```
$ cat roman
Ⅱ
Ⅲ
```

nut when I sort this file with `sort -u`, only one line is displayed:

```
$ sort -u roman
Ⅱ
```

`Ⅱ` is code-point U+2161 and `Ⅲ` is code-point U+2162.  Why is only one line displayed?

**EDIT**

```
$ xxd -g 1 roman
0000000: e2 85 a1 0a e2 85 a2 0a                          ........


$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

My `sort` is of GNU coreutils.

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.15
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

Comment: Can you provide a hexdump of the file, and dump your locale and collation relevant environment variables?

Comment: So, what is the solution?

Comment: @UniMouS - which version of sort is this? BSD sort? GNU sort? something else?

Comment: @UniMouS, LC_COLLATE, which you've included, is the main one.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/why-does-ls-sorting-ignore-non-alphanumeric-characters explains how UTF-8 sorting ignores some code-points, but I don't know why it would ignore code-points in the Number (letter) category.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `LC_COLLATE=C`; does that fix it?  This works for me:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
$ export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
$ export LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
$ export LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
$ export LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=
$ sort -u foo.txt |wc -l         # <-- with your env variables
1
$ export LC_COLLATE=C
$ sort -u foo.txt |wc -l         # <-- with LC_COLLATE changed to C
2
```

Looking at my copy of /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US, I see:

```
LC_COLLATE
% Copy the template from ISO/IEC 14651
copy "iso14651_t1"
END LC_COLLATE
```

Which is presumably where this is coming from.  Not sure why it's telling these to collate together though.

Comment: Did you do "export LC_COLLATE=C" (if bash/sh) or "setenv LC_COLLATE=C" (csh)?  In my tests, this works (though I'm using a different version of sort)

Comment: Oh, it works... I misspelled that variable :-(, but why this can work?

Comment: Take a look at the page that @Mike Samuel pointed you at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/why-does-ls-sorting-ignore-non-alphanumeric-characters